# virtual domain doesn't work in wamp (not found)

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, wamp, http-status-code-404, virtualhost

I have problem with local host 
I have cms and when I upload on host server it's working without any problems. But on local host when I run in url for example: test.local then run but test.local/login doesn't run (Not Found The requested URL /login was not found on this server.) but its run on host server

I added this 127.0.0.1 test.local to hosts file
also i added

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot c:/dev/wamp/www/test
 ServerName test.local
</VirtualHost>
```

and edited this code

```
<Directory c:/dev/workspace/web/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to htptd.conf

htaccess file:
        Options -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff)$
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: For a URL like `/login` to work, it is most likely using mod_rewrite, and for that to work inside .htaccess files, `AllowOverride` must include `FileInfo`

Comment: hi ,i added ataccess file, i actived rewrite_mod from apache

Comment: You still need to change `AllowOverride`, otherwise you are _not allowed_ to configure rewriting in htaccess.

Comment: hi , i added top code to httpd.conf but i got this error and loader.php in index.php cant loaded the files : ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function getRequestUri() in C:\dev\workspace\web\gift\index.php on line 4

Comment: hi again . i added top code to httpd.conf but i just got that error

Comment: please help me i have problem yet